# Creating a home server to act as a wifi access point and home router (Ubuntu server 18.04)

Tags: networking, server, ethernet, network-bridge, wireless-access-point

I'd like to set up a home server with several responsibilities

- Wireless AP for local networking
- Ethernet switch for local networking of various devices (HTPC, networked printer, etc)
- Home firewall and internet gateway
- general file server and more (not related to this question)

I have a machine with a 4 port ethernet card, as well as two ethernet ports on the motherboard. I've plugged in a USB wireless adpator capable of AP mode.

```
root@dagda:~# ifconfig -a | grep flags
enp3s0f0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
enp3s0f1: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
enp4s0f0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
enp4s0f1: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
enp7s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
enp8s0: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
wlx24050ff70bf6: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
```

My fiber modem is connected to `enp7s0` via ethernet, which has a static IP address of `10.0.0.2` where the modem is `10.0.0.1`, set up via netplan

```
root@dagda~# cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp7s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [10.0.0.2/24, ]
      gateway4:  10.0.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [89.19.64.164, 89.19.64.36]
```

The wireless card is capable of access point mode

```
root@dagda:~# iw list | grep -A 5 "Supported interface modes"
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO
```

and I have successfully managed to set up DNS and DHCP over the wireless interface directly so I know all that works, but what I'm trying to do is have one single IP address for the local networking side. I figured I should be able to bridge all the local interfaces (ethernet and wifi) then assign the bridge a static IP address and run dnsmasq on the bridge to provide DNS and DHCP to all local devices regardless of how they are connected, see diagram below

```
                         | ---------- home server ---------- |
                         |                                   |
                         |                 wlx24050ff70bf6   |
                         |                        ^          |
                         |                        |          |
internet <--> modem <--> | enp7s0 <--NAT--> br0 <-+          |
                         |                        |          |
                         |                        v          |
                         |                  enp[34]s0f[01]   |
                         |                                   |
                         | --------------------------------- |
```

My problem comes when I'm trying to create the bridge

```
root@dagda:~# brctl addbr br0
root@dagda:~# for p in 3 4; do
> for f in 0 1; do
> brctl addif br0 enp${p}s0f${f}
> done
> done
root@dagda:~# brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.002655dbfd80   no      enp3s0f0
                            enp3s0f1
                            enp4s0f0
                            enp4s0f1
root@dagda:~# brctl addif br0 wlx24050ff70bf6
can't add wlx24050ff70bf6 to bridge br0: Operation not supported
```

I tried to find out why this might be happening, and came across [this question on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/597834/bridging-wifi-to-ethernet-on-ubuntu-not-working) in which an answer claims you can't bridge wifi and ethernet, however the weird thing is, if I set up the bridge in netplan (config below), I can add the wifi interface to the bridge, *but* then connecting to the wifi via my phone claims it's a WEP network, despite my settings in hostpad.conf explicitly allowing only WPA2.
I cannot reproduce this now though, unfortunately.

I would like for my server to have an internal/local IP address of `192.168.0.1` regardless of which interface traffic comes in on. How can I achieve this?

https://superuser.com/questions/597834/bridging-wifi-to-ethernet-on-ubuntu-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AHa! I figured it out. It's a matter of sequencing. `hostapd` needs to be running and to have put your wireless interface into AP mode. Once it's in AP mode, `brctl ifadd br0 <wireless interface>` works just fine.

Credit goes to mattbuford for [this post](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/howto-bridge-wireless-and-wired-network-interfaces-369455/#post4410213)